# How to serialize xml tag with xlink:href

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb

When you have xml like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gml:FeatureCollection>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <imkl:Foo gml:id="Foo_1">
            <imkl:Bar xlink:href="Bar_1"/>
            <key>valueFoo</key>
        </imkl:Foo>
    </gml:featureMember>
    <gml:featureMember>
        <imkl:Bar gml:id="Bar1">
            <key>valueBar</key>
        </imkl:Bar>
    </gml:featureMember>
</gml:FeatureCollection>
```

Where the `Foo` tag contains a `Bar` tag with a `xlink:href` attribute, that points to a tag that actually contains the tags that need to be parsed. How to tell jackson to work with this?

Does jackson support this out of the box at all, or do I have to parse this manually?

I tried:

*Bar class*

```
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlID;

public class Bar{

   @Id
   @XmlID
   @XmlElement
   private String id; //should be "Bar_1"

   private String key; //should be "valueBar"

   ...
}
```

*Foo class*

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlIDREF;

public class Foo{

   @Id
   @XmlID
   @XmlElement
   private String id; //should be "Foo_1"

   private String key; //should be "valueFoo"

   @XmlIDREF
   @XmlElement(name = "Bar")
   private Bar bar; //Should be Bar with id "Bar_1" and key with "valueBar"

   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to parse inner attribute, if so, you can simply use a [XmlAttribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html):

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
    // Simplified XML
    String str = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>" +
            "    <GebiedsinformatieLevering id=\"nl.imkl-KA0000._GebiedsinformatieLevering_19O081120-1\">\n" +
            "        <belanghebbende href=\"nl.imkl-KL1011._Belanghebbende_19O081120-1\"/>\n" +
            "    </GebiedsinformatieLevering>";
    GebiedsinformatieLevering levering = mapper.readValue(str.getBytes(), GebiedsinformatieLevering.class);
    System.out.println(levering.getBelanghebbende().getHref());
}

public static class Belanghebbende {
    @XmlAttribute
    private String href;

    // getters & setters
}

public static class GebiedsinformatieLevering {
    private String text;

    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlElement(name = "belanghebbende")
    private Belanghebbende belanghebbende;

    @XmlID
    @XmlElement
    private String id;

    // getters & setters
}
```

}

Output:

> nl.imkl-KL1011._Belanghebbende_19O081120-1

Or did you need this link as an identifier for another entry?

> ```
> <imkl:Belanghebbende gml:id="nl.imkl-KL1011._Belanghebbende_19O081120-1">
> ```

Comment: I simplified my question. I just want to load `Foo` with the instance of Bar that has the corresponding id.